# Does CreateInstance objects need to be expicitly destroyed in the destructor?

Tags: c++, createinstance

This is my constructor:

```
CMSATools::CMSATools()
{
    m_pInterface = NULL;

    HRESULT hr;
    hr = m_pInterface.CreateInstance(__uuidof(MSAToolsLibrary::MSAToolsLibraryClass));
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        // TODO     }
}
```

m_pInterface is defined:

```
MSAToolsLibrary::IMSAToolsLibraryInterfacePtr m_pInterface;
```

Comment: You want to know whether `m_pInterface` needs to be released in the CMSATools distructor??

Comment: The behavior of `m_pInterface` depends on `m_pInterface`: its type and current state. You don't show that. COM objects, which this appears to be, are reference counted, and if you're not using a smart pointer then you need to call its `AddRef` and `Release` methods as appropriate. Either handle copying of your object, or disable copying.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Please see updated question.

Comment: Oh, that looks like a smart pointer. Then you only need to decide about copying. If you allow copying of `CMSATools` objects, should the copy share `IMSAToolsLibraryInterface` with the original, or not? But this looks like a class where disabling copying is best. Just declare copy constructor and copy assignment operator as `= delete`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `m_pInterface` is a smart COM object pointer, like [CComPtr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezzw7k98.aspx), you do not need to explicitly destroy it.  When the smart pointer goes out of scope, like when the `~CMSATools` destructor is called, or when the smart pointer is assigned a new value, it decrements the reference count of the COM object that it is currently holding a pointer to.  When the COM object's reference count falls to 0, it destroys itself.

Comment: Yes, it is a smart COM object pointer: `_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(IMSAToolsLibraryInterface, __uuidof(IMSAToolsLibraryInterface));`.